# Error after build AIR for desktop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there a way to debug a application after it´s build?
It works perfectly in the IDE (Flash), when I build and execute, it just stop during the execution.

Comment: Try building an app with debug mode, and start it outside Flash IDE with a standalone debug flash player of desired version (there might be issues with different major versions that don't arise in other versions). If your Flash app would stop, the debugger player will throw you an exception window which you can then use to debug your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Permit Debugging option in the Publish Settings then you should be able to connect to the Flash debugger while running the app.

When you start the app you should see a message that it's trying to connect to the debugger in Flash go to Debug > Begin Remote Debug Session and it should connect to the app.